# The isolated point in Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

We call a point $x$ of a topological space isolated if $\{x\}$ is open.
Let $X$ be a nonempty compact Hausdorff space without isolated points.
Prove that $|X| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$.

In this question I dont want to just show that $X$ is uncountable. But I want to prove that the set $S = \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ that contains of all binary sequences has the same cardinality
as $\mathbb{R}$ suffices to find an injective function $f : S \to X$.

I will be really really thankful for any help.

Comment: And what is $R$?

Comment: Is this question about proving $|X|\ge|\Bbb R|$ or proving $|\{0,1\}^\Bbb N|=|\Bbb R|$?

Comment: |X|≥|ℝ| but I use S={0,1}^ℕ I think to make it easy in order to find an injective function

Comment: Do you know what Baire spaces are? Do you know that compact Hausdorff spaces are Baire?

Comment: Do you know the construction of the Cantor set?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard idea from the construction of the Cantor set: splitting closed sets into parts. Here we will use open sets (and their closures), as we know a basic fact for a $T_1$ space without isolated points: all open sets are infinite (a finite open set implies an isolated point).

Let $\Sigma^\ast$ be the set of finite sequences of $0$ and $1$ ,including the empty one $\varepsilon$ .If $\sigma = (s_0,\ldots,s_n)$ we denote by $s \smallfrown 0$ the sequence with one extra $0$, so $((s_0,\ldots,s_n,0)$ and similarly for $s \smallfrown 1$, as well.

Now we define for each $\sigma \in \Sigma^\ast$, a non-empty open set $U_\sigma$ such that the following holds for all $\sigma$

- $\overline{U_{\sigma \smallfrown 0}} \cup \overline{U_{\sigma \smallfrown 1}} \subset U_\sigma$
- $\overline{U_{\sigma \smallfrown 0}} \cap \overline{U_{\sigma \smallfrown 1}} =\emptyset$

It's clear this can be done as we can start with $U_\varepsilon = X$ and each intermediate $U_\sigma$ is infinite, and has two open subsets with disjoint closures by regularity etc. So a recursive construction (having defined $U_\sigma$, find $U$ for its two extensions) never ends.

Now for each $x \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ denote by $x|n$ the sequence of the first $n$ coordinates of $x$, $(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}), x|0= \varepsilon$.

Now for a fixed $x$ we have that $\overline{U_{x|n}}$ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty closed sets, so it has non-empty intersection in a compact space. Define $f(x)$ to be some chosen point in that intersection: 
$$f(x)\in \bigcap \overline {U_{x|n}}$$

If $x \neq y \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, there is a first coordinate $m$ where $x_m \neq y_m$, say (WLOG) $x_m =0, y_m=1$, so that $x|m =y|m$.

Then $f(x) \in \overline{U_{x|m \smallfrown 0}}$, $f(y) \in  \overline{U_{y|m \smallfrown 1}}= \overline{U_{x|m \smallfrown 1}}$ and by construction these are disjoint so $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

So $f$ is injective from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ into $X$, proving the claim.